# Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST<Contact>

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger VerifyExistingPcList on PACTPackage__Test_Result__c (after Insert)
{              
    List<Contact> contObj = [Select LastName,Id,PACTPackage__User_Id__c,Email from Contact where LastName !=NULL limit 1];

                 for(PACTPackage__Test_Result__c t : Trigger.NEW)
                 {

                    if(contObj.PACTPackage__User_Id__c == t.PACTPackage__User_Id__c )
                         {
                             Certification__C c=new Certification__C();
                         }

                      Else if(contObj.Email == t.PACTPackage__Contact_Email_ID__c)
                          {
                              Certification__C c=new Certification__C();
                          }

                       else
                           {
                               Contact c=new Contact(LastName='Nani');
                                //c.add(contObj.Name);

                          }

                         }
 }
```

Comment: It's better if you can explain the issue and where it occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are comparing list with single sobject ,hence it is showing these error ,see below changes of your code .

```
trigger VerifyExistingPcList on PACTPackage__Test_Result__c (after Insert)
{              
    List<Contact> contObj = [Select LastName,Id,PACTPackage__User_Id__c,Email from Contact where LastName !=NULL limit 1];

                 for(PACTPackage__Test_Result__c t : Trigger.NEW)
                 {

                    if(contObj[0].PACTPackage__User_Id__c == t.PACTPackage__User_Id__c )
                         {
                             Certification__C c=new Certification__C();
                         }

                      Else if(contObj[0].Email == t.PACTPackage__Contact_Email_ID__c)
                          {
                              Certification__C c=new Certification__C();
                          }

                       else
                           {
                               Contact c=new Contact(LastName='Nani');
                                //c.add(contObj.Name);

                          }

                         }
 }
```

as list is a collection of data ,you can't compare with it single sobject .

Comment: I think this solution will Lead you to Null pointer exception issue, hence following solution posted by Sneha Kem is perfect though.......

Answer (score 2):

```
trigger VerifyExistingPcList on PACTPackage__Test_Result__c (after Insert)
{              
    List<Contact> contObj = [Select LastName,Id,PACTPackage__User_Id__c,Email from Contact where LastName !=NULL limit 1];

    for(PACTPackage__Test_Result__c t : Trigger.NEW)
    {
          if(contObj!=null && contObj.size()>0){
                  if(contObj[0].PACTPackage__User_Id__c == t.PACTPackage__User_Id__c )
                  {
                          Certification__C c=new Certification__C();
                  }
                  Else if(contObj[0].Email == t.PACTPackage__Contact_Email_ID__c)
                  {
                          Certification__C c=new Certification__C();
                  }
          }
          else
          {
                  Contact c=new Contact(LastName='Nani');
                  //c.add(contObj.Name);
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: This one is the optimized one and will not lead to any Null pointer exception.

Comment: Kindly accept my solution if your problem is solved.

Comment: According to my understanding this solution resolve the problem of "List out of bound exception" instead of Null pointer exception.